# libexec not showing on folder after installation

Tags: php, macos, apache, macos-sierra

i cant load the module of php71 on apache because when i access the folder it doesnt exist "libexec" folder, cant understand whats wrong. Already installed and reinstalled... Any someone had same issue? Im working on macOS

My path is:

```
usr/local/opt/php71/
```

Folders available inside are:

```
INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
README.md           
include             
sbin
LICENSE             
bin             
lib             
share
NEWS                
homebrew.mxcl.php71.plist   
php             
var
```

Answer (score 2):

I post here my solution:

```
$ brew uninstall --force php71
$ brew uninstall --force httpd24
$ brew cleanup
$ brew doctor # fix anything that pops up
$ brew install httpd24
$ which httpd24 # should be the Cellar one, if not, brew link httpd24 / troubleshoot

$ brew install --with-httpd24 php71 # or --with-apache, both may work
$ php -v # should be 7.1.x
$ brew unlink httpd24
```

In your httpd.conf add:

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php71/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

For updates remember to (unless you actually use the brew-apache ;)):

```
$ brew link httpd24
$ # brew-php-switcher _version-that-needs-update_ # in case you use it
$ brew upgrade
$ brew unlink httpd24
```